# Some files in a library fail to linlk to spdlog but others do

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm running into something rather weird and I'm not sure how to get to the bottom of it.
I'm using `spdlog` as a library. My code is split into two libraries, one called `NativeUtils` which is built as a static library and the other is the main library called `drivermonitor`. These are Android JNI libraries and are built using Cmake. I'm including my Cmakefiles.

I have a few source files in the `NativeUtils` and what I see is that in some files if I call a spdlog function like `spdlog::info` I get a linker error however in other files I don't.

```
: && /home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android26 --sysroot=/home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libdrivermonitor.so -o /home/kartik/Projects/DriverMonitor/service/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/3n3s6c4k/obj/arm64-v8a/libdrivermonitor.so CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/src/AiProcessor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/src/DriverMonitor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/src/DriverMonitorNative.cpp.o CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/src/FrameCounter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/src/NetworkWrapper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/src/PreProcess.cpp.o CMakeFiles/drivermonitor.dir/test/NativePreProc.cpp.o  deps/NativeUtils/libNativeUtils.a  /home/kartik/Projects/DriverMonitor/deps/Snpe/lib/arm64-v8a/libSNPE.so  /home/kartik/Projects/DriverMonitor/deps/fastcv/lib/arm64-v8a/libfastcv.a  /home/kartik/Projects/DriverMonitor/deps/Snpe/lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so  _deps/fmt-build/libfmtd.a  _deps/spdlog-build/libspdlogd.a  /home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/liblog.so  /home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/libandroid.so  /home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/libmediandk.so  /home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/libjnigraphics.so  -pthread  -llog  -lc++_shared  /home/kartik/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/liblog.so  -latomic -lm && :

ld: error: undefined symbol: spdlog::details::log_msg::log_msg(spdlog::source_loc, fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>, spdlog::level::level_enum, fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>)
>>> referenced by logger.h:134 (_deps/spdlog-src/include/spdlog/logger.h:134)
>>>               AImageWrapper.cpp.o:(spdlog::logger::log(spdlog::source_loc, spdlog::level::level_enum, fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>)) in archive deps/NativeUtils/libNativeUtils.a
```

Here are my CMakeLists.txt files,
My dependencies CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(SupportLibs)

find_library(native-media mediandk)
find_library(native-log log)
find_library(native-trace android)
find_library(native-graphics jnigraphics)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(fmt
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt
        GIT_TAG 10.0.0)
FetchContent_Declare(spdlog
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog
        GIT_TAG v1.12.0)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt spdlog)

add_subdirectory(Snpe)
add_subdirectory(fastcv)
add_subdirectory(NativeUtils)
```

I'm using `FetchContent` to obtain `fmt` and `spdlog`.

This is the CMakeLists.txt for NativeUtils

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(NativeUtils)

file(GLOB sources src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB headers include/*.hpp)

add_library(NativeUtils STATIC "${sources}" "${headers}")
print_list("${sources}")
target_include_directories(NativeUtils PUBLIC inc)
target_link_libraries(NativeUtils PUBLIC snpe c++_shared)
target_link_libraries(NativeUtils PRIVATE ${native-log} fmt::fmt spdlog::spdlog fastcv)
target_compile_features(NativeUtils PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

I use a GLOB pattern to get the sources and headers.
Finally the CMakeLists.txt file for my main library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(DriverMonitor CXX)

macro(print_list)
    foreach(arg ${ARGV})
        message("  ${arg}")
    endforeach()
endmacro()

set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../deps)

add_subdirectory(${distribution_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps)
file(GLOB headers inc/drivermonitor/*.h)
file(GLOB sources src/*.cpp test/*.cpp)
add_library(drivermonitor SHARED "${headers}" "${sources}")
target_compile_features(drivermonitor PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_include_directories(drivermonitor PRIVATE inc)
target_link_libraries(
        drivermonitor
        PRIVATE
        NativeUtils
        snpe
        fastcv
        c++shared
        fmt::fmt
        spdlog::spdlog
        ${native-log}
        ${native-trace}
        ${native-media}
        ${native-graphics}
)
```

I just can't understand why in some source files there is a linker error and in others there isn't, in the same library where all the files are built with the same set of optons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem a conflict between spdlog and fmt (spdlog make use of fmt), to work around it you can do one of the following:

- Passing -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL=ON to Cmake configure command
- Set this in your CMakeLists.txt `set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 NEW)` and `set(SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL ON)` before including spdlog

Come across here when looking for solution for similar problem and was able to fix this but I'm not proficient with Cmake to give comprehend answer.